# How do you setup custom fields in a unit test on Drupal 8

Tags: unit-testing, drupal-8

I am trying to test the functionality of methods related to custom fields on the user entity.
When I try to set the value of these fields in the setup method of my unit test, I get the error: Field * is unknown.

My initial test looks like this:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Entity;
use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;
class UserTest extends BrowserTestBase
{

  /** @var \Drupal\my_module\Entity\User|false  */
  protected $user;

  protected static $modules = ['field', 'user', 'commerce_payment', 'my_module'];

  protected $strictConfigSchema = FALSE;

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser();
    $this->user->addRole('member');
    $this->user->set('field_user_abc', [['value' => '123']]);
  }

  public function testInstance1() {
    $this->assertNotEmpty($this->user->get('field_user_abc')->get(0)->getValue());
  }

}
```

It is failing at the ->set() call in the setup method.

I don't really understand why I would need to recreate the field if Drupal is bootstrapped with my project database. However, I read in some related posts that that might be the case.  Following the example in /core/modules/user/tests/src/Functional/UserCreateTest.php, I tried the following, but the result was the same...

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Entity;

use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase;

class UserTest extends BrowserTestBase
{

  protected $user;

  protected static $modules = ['field', 'user', 'commerce_payment', 'my_module'];

  protected $strictConfigSchema = FALSE;

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser();
    $this->user->addRole('member');
    $this->drupalLogin($this->user);

    // Create a field.
    $field_name = 'field_user_abc';
    FieldStorageConfig::create([
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'module' => 'core',
      'type' => 'string',
      'cardinality' => 1,
      'locked' => FALSE,
      'indexes' => [],
      'settings' => [
    'max_length' => 14,
    'is_ascii' => false,
    'case_sensitive' => false,
      ],
    ])->save();

    FieldConfig::create([
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'label' => 'ABC',
      'bundle' => 'user',
      'description' => '',
      'required' => FALSE,
      'settings' => [],
    ])->save();

    $this->user->set($field_name, [['value' => '123']]);

  }

  public function testInstance1() {
    $this->assertNotEmpty($this->user->get('field_user_abc')->get(0)->getValue());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your storage type is set to `string` instead of `text`.

You should also remove the `'module' => 'core'` and add `text` in your modules dependencies.

```
protected static $modules = ['field', 'text', 'user', 'commerce_payment', 'my_module'];

FieldStorageConfig::create([
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'type' => 'text',
  'cardinality' => 1,
  'locked' => FALSE,
  'indexes' => [],
  'settings' => [
    'max_length' => 14,
    'is_ascii' => false,
    'case_sensitive' => false,
  ],
])->save();
```

This will result in a varchar(14) in database.

Once you export the config, the field.storage.user.field_user_abc.yml will look like this :

```
uuid: 2656c022-1ff2-4868-b07d-c26ff3531aac
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - text
    - user
id: user.field_user_abc
field_name: field_user_abc
entity_type: user
type: text
settings:
  max_length: 14
  is_ascii: false
  case_sensitive: false
module: text
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```

Comment: I tried changing this to text, but it did not have any effect.  That directive refers to how the value should be stored in the database, so a type of 'string' makes sense, whereas the 'text' type is generally used in the renderable definition, referring to the form-field-type.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried removing module and also changing module to match my custom module.  Neither had an effect.

Comment: I edited my answer have a look at it. You need to add a dependency in your modules list ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time @MacSim.  I'm still seeing the same error.  Do I need FieldConfig::create()?  Perhaps there is something else going on.

`
protected static $modules = ['field', 'user', 'text', 'commerce_payment', 'my_module'];
 // ...
 FieldStorageConfig::create([
  'field_name' => 'field_common_abc',
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'module' => 'text',
  'type' => 'text',
  'cardinality' => 1,
  'locked' => FALSE,
  'indexes' => [],
  'translatable' => FALSE,
  'settings' => [
  'max_length' => 14,
  'is_ascii' => FALSE,
  'case_sensitive' => FALSE,
 ],
 ])->save();
`

Comment: Yes you need both `FieldStorageConfig` and `FieldConfig`. I created the field programmatically from a module.install without any problem installing the module from the backoffice and from the shell. It should be the same from a Test... weird. Maybe you should try to create the field before `$this->user = $this->drupalCreateUser();`

Comment: Maybe error: `Field * is unknown` refers to another field. Do you really need `commerce_payment` to be enabled for your test ?